# Beautiful Soup data extract

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Have an local .html from which I am extracting point data, parsed with BeautifulSoup but I don't know how to extract the date that is inside a `div`, the parse array is the following:

```
<div class="_a6-p"><div><div><a href="https://www.instagram.com/chuckbasspics" target="_blank">chuckbasspics</a></div><div>Jan 7, 2013, 5:41 AM</div></div></div><div class="_3-94 _a6-o"></div></div><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><div><div>
```

Any idea how to do it?

I already extracted the users and urls (href) with the following code:

```
fl_html = open('followers.html', "r")
index = fl_html.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(index, 'lxml')

usernames = soup.find_all('a', href=True)


for i in usernames:
    users.append(i.get_text(strip=True))
    url_follower.append(i['href'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bs4` API or CSS selector:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<div class="_a6-p"><div><div><a href="https://www.instagram.com/chuckbasspics" target="_blank">chuckbasspics</a></div><div>Jan 7, 2013, 5:41 AM</div></div></div><div class="_3-94 _a6-o"></div></div><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><div><div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
```

#### Extracting the date using `.get_text()` with `separator=`

You can get all text from the HTML snippet with custom separator, then `.split`:

```py
t = soup.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")
print(t[1])
```

Prints:

```
Jan 7, 2013, 5:41 AM
```

#### CSS selector

Find next sibling to `<div>` which contains `<a>`:

```py
t = soup.select_one("div:has(a) + div")
print(t.text)
```

Print:

```
Jan 7, 2013, 5:41 AM
```

#### Using `bs4` API

Time must contain  `PM` or  `AM`, so select `<div>` which contains this string:

```py
t = soup.find("div", text=lambda t: t and (" AM" in t or " PM" in t))
print(t.text)
```

Prints:

```
Jan 7, 2013, 5:41 AM
```

Comment: How is that date can be manipulate, I have to convert to UTC?